# What is the No Sim card icon for?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, sim-card, quick-settings

On Android 7, when you pull down the top bar drop-down window (Quick Settings) a grid of 3x3 icons appears with tiles like Wifi, screen rotation on/off, Aeroplane mode etc.

On my new phone with a new SIM there is an icon called "No SIM card". What is this for?

I have a dual SIM phone with only one SIM card inserted, is it there to allow me to swap them? Is there anyway to get rid of it when I only have 1 card installed?
Here is a screenshot:

[image: Quick Settings menu]

Comment: is there another icon that shows the inserted SIM card? Can you provide screenshot?

Comment: https://www.androidauthority.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/quick-settings-improved-1-840x495.jpg

Comment: "No sim card" (middle of image) ... but on the lock screen it shows my provider and with wifi turned off I can still send text messages. Strangely I only see the provider name on the lock screen, when unlocked the provider does not show on the topbar like it did with my old phone (Android 4.4)

Comment: And what's that 'Emergency calls only' icon, is that same tile?

Comment: Ah.... sorry that is not my image, I just used it to show what I see. On my quicksettings the icon is white and says 4g and under neither it I see my mobile provider name

Comment: There is no problem sending texts or phoning, I'm not restricted to emergency calls

Comment: You can remove that icon from quick settings by clicking edit and drag it to disables tiles.

Comment: Ok, but what is it for?

Comment: you said "the icon is white and says 4g ", so is it enabled? And it will make everything easy to understand if you provide screenshot.

Comment: yes, the emergency calls icon, i'm interested in the no sim card icon. I'll try and make a screenshot

Comment: Here: https://imgur.com/a/6cfD7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have pointed out that you have dual SIM phone with only one SIM card inserted, so it is obvious that given icon is a Quick Setting tile for another SIM slot, which is empty in your case, hence **No SIM card**.
That tile works same as another tile shown there for your inserted SIM. It takes you to **SIM cards** menu in Settings
If you will insert another SIM card then it will be enabled.
You can remove that icon by [enabling System UI Tuner](https://www.droid-life.com/2015/08/17/turn-on-system-ui-tuner-in-android-6-0-preview-3/) and then hide that tile by [drag and drop Quick Settings tiles.](https://www.thurrott.com/mobile/android/77434/android-7-0-nougat-tip-customize-quick-settings)